# Flutter I am calling Rest Api and showing the data in the card with list items.How to implement Read More feature for every 10 list items loaded

Tags: flutter, api, infinite-scroll

My code is as follows

```
ListView.separated(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => WalletHistoryItem(
                      walletHistory: state.walletHistory!.result![index]!),
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                      const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  itemCount: state.walletHistory?.result?.length ?? 0)
```

Here I have used bloc pattern with models, repositories,widgets or screens   under ui etc. I am fetching  the api using Apiconstants.fetch  etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show one `LoadMoreButton` at the end of your result. And handle fetching more data and adding it to your existing list by clicking the button.

```
 ListView.separated(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
     
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(height: 16),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          
          if(index == (state.walletHistory?.result?.length ?? 0) )
            return LoadMoreButton();
          
          return WalletHistoryItem(
              walletHistory: state.walletHistory!.result![index]!);
        },
        itemCount: (state.walletHistory?.result?.length ?? 0) + 1,
    )
```

Or you can use some pre-existing packages like
https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination

Comment: Thank u for ur reply. I am looking for Load More button feature after 10 items instead of scrolling so that it will expand.

Comment: AnyHow I will try your suggestions and update u asap

Comment: Yes I have tried your advice. But after the completion of total loading of data or result of items only the Load More  button is showing, instead I want to show the button for every 10 items loaded.

Comment: I want the "Show More" button after  every 10 items or cards loaded so that if the user clicks  on Show More it should Exapnd or Show more cards or for each end of page after scrolling

Comment: On clicking load more button, fetch more data and add it in the list. You would need to handle it using state management

Comment: Thanks sumit, can you pls help me with code briefly.

Comment: please help me with sample working code

Comment: Thank you Sumit really your helped me a lot but How to  Know the item count of list items  so that "  Load More" button   stops showing  after the end of list items .  Now I have achieved showing "Load More" or "Show More" at end of each page,But how to stop showing that button after the end of the list items.

Comment: You can handle it by creating a model for it, and creating one bool variable for showing load more. Use Provider or GetX to manage your state.

Comment: Sorry I did not get you.How to create a model, only number list of items should show without giving manually the number of list items.

Comment: Please answer this query    what if I dont the number of list items coming from the api  , but I want the number of list items to shown, either it is 1 or greater than 1. If the list of number of items is greater than 10, then show "Show More"  after the 10 items

Comment: When you're calling the API, you'll be storing the response locally in some list variable right? From the response, you can find the number of items you received while calling API and the total number of items in your current items list. 
I'm assuming you're not using any controller or model to handle the logic, so I'll recommend using GetX or Provider or Bloc Pattern for it. It will solve your problems

Comment: https://medium.com/@hamza39460/pagination-with-provider-state-management-in-flutter-e555046aa171
Refer this article to achieve this using Provider

Comment: Hi Sumit I have tried using the above code as advised by you  but Iam seeing the Late Initialization error saying _data  has not been initialized  even though after initializing as  "final List<String> _data;" or " late  final List<String> _data;" otherwise code works very well just with small changes I want " Show More" button only after first 10 items and later to display complete list of items on button click   if possible  "Show Less " button to go to the top of the list.